# Windows Display Settings with multiple monitors for home and work

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, external-display

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad Carbon X1 that I use both at work and at home. At work I have two 2K Samsung monitors while at home I have a 4K Asus monitor and a 1080p Acer monitor.

The setups are different, with my monitors being above my laptop screen at work and  side by side with my laptop at home. Whenever I leave work, shut down Windows, go home, plug in my monitors, and start Windows it's still using my work desktop settings and vice versa. This includes both the resolutions of the screens as well as the positioning. It takes me a minute or two to switch everything to the correct way for that location.

Is there any way to have Windows remember the desktop setting for each monitor setup? I noticed that when I go into Advanced Display Settings it still has my monitors from the other location listed until I unplug everything and plug it back in. It's annoying and would save me a few minutes of frustration every morning and evening.